# Why hadoop_home is not set correctly

Tags: java, hadoop, windows-server-2012-r2

I install hadoop 2.3 for windows folling this instruction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhxWig96dME

And I can get it work very well on my windows 8 on my Macbook.
However when I repeat the same steps on my windows server, and when I run command line: `hadoop` it shows this error:

```
HADOOP_HOME is not set correctly
```

I check again very carefully and find that HADOOP_HOME is set very precisely (as in instruction and in my previous setup on laptop).
So what could be the problem and how to fix it ?
Is there any different between setting up for laptop and server ? I notice that when I run the same java installation file (java se: chromeinstall-8u45.exe), it give the different results on laptop and server (different number of directories).

Answer (score 0):

Do not set or use HADOOP_HOME; it is an unsupported env-var in CDH4 
onwards. Instead, map your HDFS directory to "HADOOP_PREFIX" instead.

Comment: Looks like I also found solution just now: I add this line: export HADOOP_HOME=c:\hadoop-2.3.0  to hadoop-env.sh in etc\hadoop folder. Thanks anyway ! Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, its not fixed by my method. So how do I map that HDFS directory? Do you mean the hadoop-2.3.0 directory path? And do I create New, then name: "Hadoop_prefix" and path to that path in the enviroment setting ?

Comment: I also tried this: set HADOOP_HOME=c:\hadoop-2.3.0
set HADOOP_PREFIX=c:\hadoop-2.3.0
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_PREFIX%\etc\hadoop
set YARN_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%
set PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin (add to hadoop-env.cmd). But it doesn't solve the problem. (I made sure that no extra space at the end of each command line added.)

Comment: have you considered removing the trailing slash from your directory path?

If that doesn't work, which packages do you have installed?  "rpm -qa 
| grep cdh" or "dpkg -l | grep cdh" as appropriate. Also what JVM are 
you using and how is that installed?

If you manually set HADOOP_*_HOME or similar you may be breaking 
something that would just work if you left it alone. :)

Comment: Yes, after trying all solution, I have to re-download the .zip file at my server and repeat the whole process. It works fine now! The problem was due to I copied the folder "hadoop..." from laptop to server and the remote connection was not stable. I checked the folder size and found out the difference. Thanks for bearing with me ! :)