# Hadoop 2.7.2 single node installation windows 10

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, installation

I am new to hadoop and I have given my best shot to try to setup hadoop single node installation on my windows machine on my own but obviously I failed and now need some help.

I followed the tutorial from [wiki.apache.org](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) and did everything as stated except the steps involving building (2.3 - 2.7) since I downloaded the binary distribution in the first place.

The problem is that after having all my files modified as the tutorial states, when I try to run the following command given at step 3.4:

```
%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin\hdfs namenode -format
```

It says:

```
+================================================================+
|      Error: HADOOP_HOME is not set correctly                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please set your HADOOP_HOME variable to the absolute path of   |
| the directory that contains the hadoop distribution            |
+================================================================+
'-Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have already adding HADOOP_HOME to my enviroment variables as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880475/why-hadoop-home-is-not-set-correctly) but it didn't work out. I tried to google **Dhadoop.security.logger** but could not find anything of much use.

Right now my hadoop-env.cmd file looks like [this](http://codepaste.net/dz8prp)

Please take a look and help me with the possible fix.

Comment: Check the property name "yarn.application.classpath" and it's values (%HADOOP_HOME%\..\..) of your yarn-site.xml configuration file.

Comment: @StaceyMorgan Thanks for your response. Here it is and I don't see HADOOP_HOME defined here. What should I add?

<property>
<name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
<value>%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%,%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*,%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*,%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*</value></property>

Comment: May be this link will help you. http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

Comment: no it didn't do the magic. Still see no hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Hadoop 2.7.2 seems to have a problem. The 2.7.1 version just worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, all config files were set correctly, all environment variables were set correctly.

My issue: I had used winZip to unzip the hadoop-2.8.0.tar.gz file and it had some issues with directory depth when unzipping. I figured I'd move on and come back to that if it was an issue. After messing around with environment variables for an hour or so, I unzipped the gz file with winRAR instead (which doesn't have directory depth issues) and then hadoop version and hdfs namenode -format starting working fine... So check to see if that's your issue as well. Basically some of the share directory probably won't be there if you used winZIP and that needs to be part of the classpath.